# Permanent Shroud of Darkness debuff

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I'm playing on elvishly easy with permadeath. At least since the 3th or 4th floor, almost every time I encounter an enemy I get debuffed with the Shroud of Darkness. 
I'm at level 7 now and the situation hasn't changed.
It is really unpleasant, since the effects stack and most of the time I can't see a single tile around me.

How can I get rid of it? Is there a way to find out what/who cast it at me? [I am playing with a handful of mods activated, but I've once beaten the game with them and never had this problem, so I don't suspect the problem lies there.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be removed with a Potion of Purity or a Zodiacal Wand, though curse removal is likely something you'd prefer to save.

It is cast by Witchy, Monstrous Mask, Squiddy, and Lord Dredmor. If you can eliminate any of those, it wears off in a reasonable amount of time.

If you have something that gives additional sight radius, it might be worth an equipment slot to counteract some of the curse's effect directly. Non-equipment sources of sight radius include potions of Clear Vision, Astrology's Radiant Aura spell, and the Perception skill.

Comment: I read about the monsters that cast it; I also have both Astrology and Perception. Still, I had the feeling I got cursed even when I only fought diggles. :/ [Am I seeing things? Wth?]

Comment: At this point I'm wondering if maybe you have cursed equipment that randomly afflicts you with Shroud of Darkness, but it's hard to find information on such things. Plus such an item could have been introduced through a mod, but you simply didn't encounter it on your previous runs. Maybe check out what you're wearing?

Comment: That occurred to me, too. If that is the case, does the item _have_ to state it somewhere in the description? Or can the effect be hidden?

Comment: Well, the Fruitful Staff is an example of an item that proves that the code doesn't require effects must be listed, even though it happens to in its text description.